# How to continue to next item in iterator using recursive_directory_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I am currently iterating through a filesystem. I want to capture any errors that occur and then just continue iterating. The current behavior if an error occurs it will set the current iterator to the end and then the for loop exits. I would like for this to skip that path and continue.

```
    try {
        for (const auto& dirEntry : recursive_directory_iterator(myPath)) {
            std::cout << dirEntry << std::endl;
        }
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
        //continue iteration
    }
```

EDIT: This is my little sample that I am working with. The error occurs on the `recursive_directory_iterator`. Specifically it errors out when accessing a folder it does not have access to. I know I can add `std::filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied` and it will skip those folders, but what about just errors in general? I am not sure if that would ever occur so maybe I am overthinking it? Would permissions be the only reason this would error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't recover from errors in `recursive_directory_iterator`.

> If the `recursive_directory_iterator` reports an error or is advanced past the last directory entry of the top-level directory, it becomes equal to the default-constructed iterator, also known as the end iterator.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator)

Comment: I had a feeling I would need to do something similar to this but was hoping I could some how use my current code to make it work. I am getting a error on the ```end``` on the first end.

Comment: I added more info to my question. Maybe this will change the answer some? The issue is with the ```recursive_directory_iterator```. It will throw an error before it gets to the ```try```.

Comment: @xx9000 I went and looked at the docs, turns out you are out of luck

Comment: Dang I really liked using this iterator. Can you think of a scenario when something like this would fail? Other than a permissions issue.

Comment: @xx9000 you unmount the drive while iterating it

Answer (score 0):

Just put the try/catch inside the for loop:

```
for (const auto& dirEntry : recursive_directory_iterator(myPath)) {
    try {
        std::cout << dirEntry << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
        //continue iteration
    }
}
```

Comment: The error occurs on ```const auto& dirEntry : recursive_directory_iterator(myPath)```

Comment: You should elaborate more because not looks like you are asking the wrong question or not providing enough context.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the iterator throw exceptions, you can pass in a reference to an error code when constructing the iterator, which will be used to store any errors found during iteration. The error code can then be inspected in the loop to check whether any errors occurred during iteration:

```
std::error_code ec{};
for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(..., ec)) 
{
   if (ec)
   {
     // handle error...
     ec = std::error_code{};
     continue;
   }
}
```